# Socket VS Message Broker

Tags: sockets, messagebroker

### Scenario

We are developing a cypto coin exchange platform.
The data feed is in **real time** and its from multiple sources, users can listen to global channel which transports everything or it can connect to a specific channel which will transport only data for that x coin. The platform should be able to handle **two-way communication** between client and server.

### Question

- Should we use a socket server and to relay every msg from the data feed to the users or should we use a message broker (ex: RabbitMQ, Kafka) ?
- In case we use a socket server should we use 2 instances one for the data feed and one for the two-way communication ?

Comment: I don't see how crypto is relevant to the problem. All exchanges basically do the same thing. Have you watched any presentations on Bloomberg's exchange architecture?

Comment: Yes i have but the presentation is in general terms, they never talk about the specifics or why x technology is better than y. If you know about any presentation that can answer my question i would appreciate it.

Comment: You could just look [at their Github](https://github.com/bloomberg). They use Kafka on the backend, and websockets on the frontend, though. There's very rarely a use case for a client->server interaction beyond a buy/sell/selection event, which is out-of-band with the actual real-time price ticker information, so doesn't need to be bi-directional beyond a standard API call